# Get count of customers for N records for reach group

Tags: sql

I have a table unique at cust_id level and has the following :

```
CustID  Product Country Region
1   A   US  NA
2   A   US  NA
3   A   US  NA
4   A   US  NA
5   A   US  NA
6   B   US  NA
7   B   US  NA
8   B   US  NA
9   B   US  NA
10  C   US  NA
11  C   US  NA
12  C   US  NA
13  C   US  NA
14  D   US  NA
15  D   US  NA
16  D   US  NA
17  E   US  NA
18  E   US  NA
19  A   UK  EMEA
20  A   UK  EMEA
21  A   UK  EMEA
22  A   UK  EMEA
23  A   UK  EMEA
24  B   UK  EMEA
25  B   UK  EMEA
26  B   UK  EMEA
27  B   UK  EMEA
28  C   UK  EMEA
29  C   UK  EMEA
30  C   UK  EMEA
31  C   UK  EMEA
32  D   UK  EMEA
33  D   UK  EMEA
34  D   UK  EMEA
35  E   UK  EMEA
36  E   UK  EMEA
```

I am looking for a SQL query that will return top 4(N) products used in a country and region along with the number of customers using each product. The output will look like this :

```
Region  Country Product Count ( Distinct ( cust_id ))
NA  US  A   5
NA  US  B   4
NA  US  C   4
NA  US  D   3
UK  EMEA    A   4
UK  EMEA    B   4
UK  EMEA    C   4
UK  EMEA    D   3
```

Help please.Thanks!

Comment: hi, welcome to stack overflow. which is the database you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation with a window function for this:

```
select rcp.*
from (select region, country, product, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by region, country order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by region, country, product
     ) rcp
where seqnum <= 4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Gordon! Worked like magic. 

The only small change I had to make was to name the expression count (*) 
```
select rcp.*
from (select region, country, product, count(*) as cust#,
             row_number() over (partition by region, country order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by region, country, product
     ) rcp
where seqnum <= 4
```